# How to FORCEFULLY kill a WorkflowInstance?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a somewhat unusual scenario where I need to be able to outright slaughter "hung", self-hosted `WorkflowInstance`'s after a given timeout threshold.  I tried the `Abort()`, `Terminate()` and `Cancel()` methods but these are all too "nice".  They all appear to require a response from the WorkflowInstance before they are honored.

In my scenario, a workflow entered an infinite loop and was therefore unresponsive. Calls to the normal methods mentioned above would simply hang since the workflow was completely unresponsive.  I was surprised to learn the `WorkflowRuntime` does not appear have a mechanism for dealing with this scenario, or that `Abort()` and `Terminate()` are merely suggestions as opposed to violent directives.

I scoured google/msdn/stackoverflow/etc trying to find out what to do when `Terminate()` simply isn't going to get the job done and came up dry. I considered creating my own base activity and giving it a timeout value so my "root" activity can kill itself if one of its child activities hangs.  This approach seems like I'd be swatting at flies with a sledge hammer...

Is there a technique I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only true solution is to consider this a bug, fix whatever went wrong, and consider the matter closed.

The only way to forcibly abort *any* code that is locked in an infinite loop is to call `Abort()` on the thread.  Of course, this is considered bad juju, and should only be done when the state of the application can be ensured after the call.

So, you must supply the [WorkflowApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.hosting.workflowinstance.synchronizationcontext.aspx) an implementation of [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) that you write which can call `Abort()` on the thread that the workflow [Post()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx)s to.

Comment: The fact that it was allowed to execute at all is indeed a symptom of the real problem, which is a bug that squirmed it's way into an environment it should have never made it to.  Agreed, and also the subject of much discussion with my team this week...  My hope is to provide some manner of failsafe should this kind of code ever somehow make it out of a dev environment in the future, in addition to improving the code promotion process, which is probably enough for an entirely new question all by itself.  I'd like to avoid manhandling the thread itself, but that might just be how it is.

Comment: Also, this is highly likely to become the answer, much as I don't want it to be...  I didn't stop to think of it as a straight threading issue.  I was hoping to leverage some plumbing of the WorkflowRuntime to do the heavy lifting for me.  Keeping it open for a bit to see if any other angles can be pursued, but unfortunately this is probably dead-on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, but have you tried the WorkflowInstance.TryUnload() function? I remember this to fire off a few events inside of the workflow (been a while since I did this), so you might be able to have an event handler in your workflow that catches this and does a kill switch on itself.